# Why is PHP showing me this error

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there fellow overflower's, I am stuck on an issue which I am unsure why PHP is throwing at me, I believe I have defined it in my text but PHP thinks otherwise. I get the following error(s)

Notice: Undefined variable: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\wd1_vtec_0100348514\index.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined variable: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\wd1_vtec_0100348514\index.php on line 32

This is my code on page index.php..

```
  <div class="masthead">

    <div class="sliding-car">
    <img src="main/img/subaru.jpg" alt="Subaru">
</div>
  </div>

  <hr>


  <div class="jumbotron">
    <p class="lead">Enter your Username & Password</p>

    <?php if(isset($_GET['message']))


    //Alert messages based on integers
    if($message == 1) {
    echo '
    <div class="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>Invalid username or password</strong>
    </div>
    ';
    }

    else if($message == 2) {
    echo '
    <div class="alert alert-success">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>You have successfully logged out! </strong>
    </div>
    ';
    }

    ?>


    <form action="auth_check.php" method="post" class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input name="username" type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Username">
    <input name="password" type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password">    
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>

  </form>


    <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="register.php">Register New User</a>
  </div>

<div class="sliding-car">
    <img src="main/img/subaruswag.png" alt="Subaru">
</div>
```

Any help would be much apreciated! Thanks!!!

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['message']))` doesn't automagically create a variable called `$message` these days... that functionality was disabled in PHP many years ago (for security reasons), so you need to assign it explicitly in your code

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to assign `$_GET['message']` to `$message` variable.

```
$message = $_GET['message'];
```

Answer (score 0):

change $message with $_GET['message'] or set variable $message. Example: $message = $_GET['message']